# Notification Email Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript, designer-workflow, custom-list

Working in SharePoint 2013 Designer.  Created an notification email to be sent 30 days before the due date.  I used the workflow to start using `If Workflow Context:Association: Start on Item Creation equals yes`and pause until the notification date equals Today.  I did not use `Add Time to Date` action because it doesn't work in my environment. Using `workflow context:association` sometimes the workflow successfully works but other times no emails are sent.

Question, Other than a third party solution, is there a more reliable way to guarantee an notification email will be sent? Why doesn't `workflow context:association` no longer working all the time?

Comment: Why doesn't add time to date work in your environment? What happens when you add it to a workflow? That is definitely the correct way to do what you're wanting.

Comment: There's no reason for you to use the workflow context. Why did you try that?

Comment: I am not sure why it doesn't work in my environment, but it doesn't.  The workflow context has worked but not reliable each time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the due date as part of the workflow?  we do something similar

We create a workflow variable which is created date + X days, you could then create another which is this workflow variable+30days.

You can then pause until this workflow variable date then send your email.

Comment: No, I set the due date as a calculated column.  Are you using the Add Time to Date action?